# Django-Tables2 get current page number

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a simple Table where I use a LinkColumn to access a view which toggles a value from true to false, unfortunately this resets my list to the first page.

Now it should be possible to pass a specific page into the table object:

```
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page=25)
    return render(request, "people_listing.html", {"table": table})
```

How can I pass the current page number to my view? The request does not include this info and I can't seem to reference self in the Table Class (which has an attribute Page at least)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got a solution but probably way too complicated (there has to be an easier way to obtain the Page Info directly...)

Views:

```
# Get the relative position in the Queryset with the same filters as in the ListView
    position = list(CustomModel.objects.filter(column='1234').values_list('id', flat=True)).index(obj.id)

# Calculate the Page Number (assuming 10 Entries per Page)
    if pk <= 10:
        page_number = 1
    else:
        page_number = int((10 + position)/10)


# Rebuild the Table Object and set the page_number to the desired page
    table = MyTable(CustomModel.objects.filter(column='1234'))
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", page_number), per_page=10)

    return render(request, "my_app/my_page.html", {"table": table})
```